# How can I package 3 large boxes together into one shipment?

Tags: packaging

I have 3 boxes that I need to return to Amazon, and they only gave me 1 label, but the items came individually in their own 24" x 30" x 6" boxes, and I don't have a box that can fit them all. Because they're all identically sized, and I had a [fancy-schmancy machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prDvbh-rdnY), I could strap them according to UPS guidelines. The local UPS store doesn't have (or won't admit to having) a strapper.

My ideas have been to use a bunch of paper from paper bags along with a bunch of tape to basically make a form-fitting "bag"...but that might get shredded pretty quickly. I could also manually strap them with some wire (soldered together), but the guy at the UPS store might give me some grief about my homebrew strapping.

What's a good way to bundle 3 boxes into one for shipping?

Answer (score 2):

You generally want to keep your new construction as cube-like as possible.
In your case, this would result in a 24" x 30" x 18" box.

If you have cardboard sheets available, use these as struts at the 3x6" sides to place the boxes between. Use tape or whatever you have around to keep it together. If you use rope or something similar, make sure to put the first layer on the sheets. The sheets will prevent (most of) the damage to the actual packages.

Stick the label to one of the cardboard sheets and voilà, you got yourself a package.